# Error: 'across' is not an exported object from 'namespace:collapse'

Tags: r, dplyr, r-package, r-collapse

I am learning how to use the R package `collapse` to process the data. The syntax in `collapse` is similar to `dplyr`, with similar function names. Below is an example. Both code chunks work well. But since both packages contain the function `across`. I want to know if the second code chunk is actually using the `across` function from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

# Group by cyl, then calculate mean for each columns using dplyr
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = mean)) 
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
# cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  26.7  105.  82.6  4.07  2.29  19.1 0.909 0.727  4.09  1.55
# 2     6  19.7  183. 122.   3.59  3.12  18.0 0.571 0.429  3.86  3.43
# 3     8  15.1  353. 209.   3.23  4.00  16.8 0     0.143  3.29  3.5 

# Group by cyl, then calculate mean for each columns using collapse
mtcars %>%
  fgroup_by(cyl) %>%
  fsummarise(across(.fns = fmean)) 
# cyl      mpg     disp        hp     drat       wt     qsec        vs        am     gear     carb
# 1   4 26.66364 105.1364  82.63636 4.070909 2.285727 19.13727 0.9090909 0.7272727 4.090909 1.545455
# 2   6 19.74286 183.3143 122.28571 3.585714 3.117143 17.97714 0.5714286 0.4285714 3.857143 3.428571
# 3   8 15.10000 353.1000 209.21429 3.229286 3.999214 16.77214 0.0000000 0.1428571 3.285714 3.500000
```

I then tried the following code, specifying the `across` function from the `collapse` package, but it leads to an error.

```
mtcars %>%
  fgroup_by(cyl) %>%
  fsummarise(collapse::across(.fns = fmean))
```

> Error in fsummarise(., collapse::across(.fns = fmean)) :
> expressions need to be named or start with across(), or its shorthand
> acr().

It turns out `collapse::across` leads to an error showing that `across` is not in the `collapse` package.

```
collapse::across
```

> Error: 'across' is not an exported object from 'namespace:collapse'

`collapse:::across` shows the functions as follows.

```
function (.cols = NULL, .fns, ..., .names = NULL, .apply = "auto", 
    .transpose = "auto") 
{
    stop("across() can only work inside fmutate() and fsummarise()")
}
<bytecode: 0x0000018a76156648>
<environment: namespace:collapse>
```

But the following still fails.

```
mtcars %>%
  fgroup_by(cyl) %>%
  fsummarise(collapse:::across(.fns = fmean))
```

> Error in fsummarise(., collapse:::across(.fns = fmean)) :
> expressions need to be named or start with across(), or its shorthand
> acr().

I want to know why `collapse::across` could not export the function, and if there are alternatives to specify a function in a specific package.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks. Are you using `R 4.2.2` and `collapse 1.8.9`?

Comment: The issue is caused by this line in `fsummarise()` where using anything but the bare function names `across`/`acr` causes the check to fail: `if (ei[[1L]] != quote(across) && ei[[1L]] != quote(acr))`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks. So `fsummarise` can only accept `across/acr` as the function inside. It would still be nice if there is a way to specify which `across` to use.

Comment: Can I ask what the goal is here?  Given that `across()` whether it be for `dplyr` or `collapse` only work in the context of other functions in their respective package being able to specify which `across()` to use is redundant because you could only specify one - they're not interchangeable. Re the statement"I want to know if the second code chunk is actually using the across function from dplyr"  - it is not, it shares the name and the functionality but is an entirely different function.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I am writing my own functions with my workspace both loaded with `dplyr` and `collapse`. I thought it is a good practice to specify which `across` function I am using. But based on your explanation, both `summarise` and `fsummarise` can load their associated `across` function correctly, then I will not need to worry about that.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I can move on with my actual work now. The only thing left is why `collapse::across` does not work. I was taught that `package::function name` is the way to export a function from a package, but probably not for all of them, which is fine. If someone can provide some explanation on that, I will be grateful and accept his/her answer.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento By the way, I am also curious how `summarise` and `fsummarise` can load their associated `across` functions correctly without being confused. But if the explanations are beyond the scope of question in Stack Overflow, then it is fine. As I mentioned, I can continue my work now.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks. So you are saying some functions in a package are internal function and could not be exported?

Comment: This should be written up as an answer, but the package author is active and may post an authoritative response.  What I believe is happening is 1) `across` does not exist as an exported function, although it is documented. 2) The internal function `across` exists just to error if called in an incorrect context. 3) Calling `across` in `fsummarise`/`fmutate` results in the call being captured and replaced with the internal function `do_across`. Presumably it has been implemented this way to provide a familiar `dplyr`-like interface but to avoid conflict with `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *collapse*, `across()` is an internal function only for use inside `fsummarise()` and `fmutate()`. It can be abbreviated using `acr()`. It does not have any use outside `fsummarise` and `fmutate`, and therefore does not need to be exported (which avoids namespace conflicts with *dplyr* and me having to create `facross()` or something like that).

Since `fsummarise()` and `fmutate()` lazily evaluate expressions, they will detect that `across()` is being passed, and will always use the *collapse* version. They do not support `dplyr::across()` and also were not meant to parse something like `collapse:::across()`, which is dangerous and redundant.

So if *collapse* is not attached, using `collapse::fsummarise(across(...))` is sufficient.